# How do table and ftable differ?

Tags: r, contingency

The documentation for `ftable` tells us that "*`ftable` creates ‘flat’ contingency tables*". However, the meaning of this isn't getting through to me. I've placed two examples below, but they look so similar that I feel like I'm completely missing the distinction between `table` and `ftable`. Am I ignorant of some critical programming or statistical idea?

```
> ftable(mtcars[c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear")])
          gear  3  4  5
cyl vs am              
4   0  0        0  0  0
       1        0  0  1
    1  0        1  2  0
       1        0  6  1
6   0  0        0  0  0
       1        0  2  1
    1  0        2  2  0
       1        0  0  0
8   0  0       12  0  0
       1        0  0  2
    1  0        0  0  0
       1        0  0  0
```

```
> table(mtcars[c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear")])
, , am = 0, gear = 3

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  0  1
  6  0  2
  8 12  0

, , am = 1, gear = 3

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  0  0
  6  0  0
  8  0  0

, , am = 0, gear = 4

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  0  2
  6  0  2
  8  0  0

, , am = 1, gear = 4

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  0  6
  6  2  0
  8  0  0

, , am = 0, gear = 5

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  0  0
  6  0  0
  8  0  0

, , am = 1, gear = 5

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  1  1
  6  1  0
  8  2  0
```

My suspicion is that it means "flat" as in "flattern a nested list", but if that was the case, then I'm not sure why I cannot feed exactly the same arguments to `ftable` as I can `table`. For example, `ftable(Titanic, row.vars = 1:3)` is valid, but `table(Titanic, row.vars = 1:3)` throws an error about the arguments having non-equal lengths.

Comment: The second one is an array of 4D

Comment: @akrun I don't think that it's just a printing convenience. See my most recent edit.

Comment: I meant the dimensions are different for `ftable` and the table you constructed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the structure, it is evident from the `dim` attributes

```
tbl1 <- table(mtcars[c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear")])

str(tbl1)
 'table' int [1:3, 1:2, 1:2, 1:3] 0 0 12 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ cyl : chr [1:3] "4" "6" "8"
  ..$ vs  : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  ..$ am  : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  ..$ gear: chr [1:3] "3" "4" "5"

ftbl1 <- ftable(mtcars[c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear")])
str(ftbl1)
 'ftable' int [1:12, 1:3] 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 12 0 ...
 - attr(*, "row.vars")=List of 3
  ..$ cyl: chr [1:3] "4" "6" "8"
  ..$ vs : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  ..$ am : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
 - attr(*, "col.vars")=List of 1
  ..$ gear: chr [1:3] "3" "4" "5"
```

i.e. flat table is 2D, while the `table` is a 4D array

```
dim(tbl1)
#[1] 3 2 2 3

dim(ftbl1)
#[1] 12  3
```

Note that both of them are `array`s, and an `array` is also a `vector` with some `dim` attributes.

Both are not `list`s.  It is the attributes that make them different and how they are arranged.  e.g. if we remove the attributes, they are just `vector`s arranged in different order of values

```
c(ftbl1)
#[1]  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  2  6  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  2  0  0
c(tbl1)
#[1]  0  0 12  1  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0  2  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  2  1  0  0
```

Check if it is a `list`

```
is.list(tbl1)
#[1] FALSE
is.list(ftbl1)
#[1] FALSE
```

---

Regarding the error in `table`, it is just that it doesn't have the `row.vars` argument if we check the `?table`

> table(...,
> exclude = if (useNA == "no") c(NA, NaN),
> useNA = c("no", "ifany", "always"),
> dnn = list.names(...), deparse.level = 1)

whereas `?ftable`

> ftable(..., exclude = c(NA, NaN), row.vars = NULL,
> col.vars = NULL)